# Getting JavaScript commands to work in AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I have a script that opens a list of URLs in a new Safari window which works, but the JavaScript commands do not seem to be working. I stuck in a console.log, which doesn't show up in inspector too as a test which does not show up. I tried changing the delay before the JavaScript all the way up to 17.

As a side note, 'subscribe-button' is the Edit button when you are logged in, which I want clicked.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    read (item 1 of input)
    set ps to paragraphs of the result
    set tot to count ps
    tell application "Safari"
        reopen
        activate
    end tell
    repeat with i from 1 to tot
        set p to item i of ps
        if p is not "" then
            try
                tell application "Safari"
                    tell front window
                        set r to make new tab with properties {URL:p}
                        set current tab to r
                        delay 1
                        do JavaScript "console.log('test this log')"
                        do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('subscribe-button').click()"
                        if i = tot then exit repeat
                        repeat
                            delay 1
                            get URL of r
                        end repeat
                    end tell
                end tell
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end run
```

Comment: If you want help debugging code, you should to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That's really an unhelpful comment, but I answered my own question anyway.

Comment: I have no problem clicking a button using JavaScript in Safari using `do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('elementID').click()" in document 1` in the web pages I've applied it to. As to my comment about **MCVE**, that's pretty much an unspoken rule here at **SO**, but sometime reminders are necessary! **You did not provide a URL to test your code against or to look at the code in the target page, so all I could offer is what has repeatedly worked for me and others.**

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I both set the do JavsScript to "in current tab" and increase the delay, the console.log works.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    read (item 1 of input)
    set ps to paragraphs of the result
    set tot to count ps
    tell application "Safari"
        reopen
        activate
    end tell
    repeat with i from 1 to tot
        set p to item i of ps
        if p is not "" then
            try
                tell application "Safari"
                    tell front window
                        set r to make new tab with properties {URL:p}
                        set current tab to r
                        delay 10
                        do JavaScript "console.log('test this log')" in current tab
                        if i = tot then exit repeat
                        repeat
                            delay 10
                            get URL of r
                        end repeat
                    end tell
                end tell
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end run
```

Comment: Is there any reason you left out `do JavaScript "document.getElementsById('subscribe-button').click()"` in your answer? Did it click the button?

Comment: No, mainly my issue was to get the JavaScript running at all. It gave me an error the element of that idea doesn't exist, which I think might be caused from the page not being entirely loading. That could possibly be fixed with a delay, or another script which detects if the page is loaded. I'm no longer clicking the button, since I can just use a generic video edit URL with the associated YouTube video ID.